# Парсинг сайта . Данные из таблицы

Tags: python

Нужно получить данные из таблицы на сайте (Month,Price,Change) . Пишет что не находит имена в скобке
Вот код:

````
import requests

url= "https://www.indexmundi.com/commodities/?commodity=robusta-coffee&months=360"

page = requests.get(url)

print(page)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

lists = soup.find_all('section', class_="tblData")

for list in lists:
    Price = list.find('td', class_="tblData__Price")
    Month = list.find('td', class_="tblData__Month")
    Change = list.find('td', class_="tblData__Change")
info = [Price, Month, Change]
print(info)```
````

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas

ds = pandas.read_html("https://www.indexmundi.com/commodities/?commodity=robusta-coffee&months=360")
print(ds[1])

        Month  Price  Change
0    Jul 1992   0.86       -
1    Aug 1992   0.86   0.00%
2    Sep 1992   0.90   4.65%
3    Oct 1992   0.97   7.78%
4    Nov 1992   1.05   8.25%
..        ...    ...     ...
355  Feb 2022   2.41  -0.82%
356  Mar 2022   2.29  -4.98%
357  Apr 2022   2.29   0.00%
358  May 2022   2.27  -0.87%
359  Jun 2022   2.29   0.88%
```

Comment: какие пакеты нужно установить? пишет lxml not found, please install it

Comment: теперь `urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)>`

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get("https://www.indexmundi.com/commodities/?commodity=robusta-coffee&months=360")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
lists = soup.find('table', class_="tblData").find_all('tr')[1:]
for list in lists:
    info = [x.text for x in list.find_all('td')]
    print(info)
```